# Want to print a table format with multiple line in shell scipt

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I want to print the input in a table format using a tool such as `sed` or `awk`.

Input:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
```

Desired output:

```
Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4 
Line5 Line6 Line7 Line8
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a blank line between lines four and five? Are there only eight lines total?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean by "table format". Will the file always contain groups of lines separated by an empty line as in your example? Can there be more than 2 groups?

Comment: `paste - - - - <infile` or `tr -s \\n <infile | paste - - - -` if there are blanks in between... I'm sure this has been asked before...

Comment: Are the lines all the same length?  Can they include spaces?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no blank lines separating groups, then to print groups of four lines:

```
$ awk '{a=a (length(a)?OFS:"") $0} NR>1 && NR%4==0{print a; a=""}' file
Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4
Line5 Line6 Line7 Line8
```

---

If there are blank lines separating the groups of lines to be printed (like [this previous revision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/294303/5)), then:

```
$ cat file
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4

Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
$ awk '{a=a (length(a)?OFS:"") $0} !length($0){print a; a=""} END{print a}' file
Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4 
Line5 Line6 Line7 Line8
```

Comment: That will malfunction if a group's first line in the first case or any line in the second case consists of one or more digit '0' optionally preceded by '+' or '-', and thus tests as false. Safer to test `length(a)` and `! length` (implicitly $0), but simpler to always concatenate `a=a OFS $0` and remove the extra when outputting `print substr(a,2)`. For the second  case can also read in 'paragraph mode' and regenerate (with OFS default space): `awk -vRS= '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Good suggestion! Answer updated to use `length`.  I also like the `substr(a,2)` approach and I used to use it.  But, in my experience here on SE, the ternary statement approach seems to be, on average, better received.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are not all the same length,

- start with one of the answers presented so far,
- modify it, as necessary, to separate the columns with tabs (this assumes that there are no tabs in the data), and
- pipe the output through `column -t -s$'\t'`

For example (assuming no blank separator lines):

```
$ cat file178492
The
quick
brown
fox
jumps over
the
lazy
dog.
$ paste - - - - < file178492
The     quick   brown   fox
jumps over      the     lazy    dog.
                    # paste separates output columns with tabs by default.
$ paste - - - - < file178492 | column -t -s$'\t'
The         quick  brown  fox
jumps over  the    lazy   dog.
$ awk '{a=a (a?OFS:"") $0} NR>1 && NR%4==0{print a; a=""}' file178492
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog.
                    # specify  -vOFS=$'\t'  to awk to separate output fields with tabs.
$ awk -vOFS=$'\t' '{a=a (a?OFS:"") $0} NR>1 && NR%4==0{print a; a=""}' file178492
The     quick   brown   fox
jumps over      the     lazy    dog.
$ awk -vOFS=$'\t' '{a=a (a?OFS:"") $0} NR>1 && NR%4==0{print a; a=""}' file178492 | column -t -s$'\t'
The         quick  brown  fox
jumps over  the    lazy   dog.
```

Notes:

- `$'…'` is a bashism that lets you enter control characters in commands
  in an unambiguously visible and device-independent way. 
  `$'\t'` specifies a tab character. 
  If you’re not using bash, and `$'\t'` doesn’t work for you,
  try just typing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>. 
  (If those don’t work, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.)
- If you want your columns separated by more space.
  add `-o'    '` to the `column` command:

```
$ paste - - - - < file178492 | column -t -s$'\t' -o'    '
The           quick    brown    fox
jumps over    the      lazy     dog.
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you just want to print the grouped sections on a single line, this basic awk script should do that.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{gsub("\n"," ");print}' test.txt
```